# Finding the closest number to another number out of two arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have two arrays and a ratio I want to get as close to as possible. On number from the array gets divided by the other number from the array. This equals the ratio. I want to get as close as possible to the given ratio, comparing all combinations of the numbers in the given array and then output the locations of the two chosen values.

This is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] gearsA = {20, 14, 26};
    int[] gearsB = {18, 16, 14, 24};

    pos = nearestRatioPos(gearsA, gearsB, 0.8);
    System.out.print(pos[0] + " " + pos[1]);
}

public static int[] nearestRatioPos(int[] gearsA, int[] gearsB, double ratio){

    int[] posRetRatio = new int[2];
    int i, j;
    double bestDistance = Math.abs(((double)gearsA[0] / (double)gearsB[0]) -
            ratio), distance = 0;

    for(i = 0; i <= gearsA.length - 1; i++){
        for(j = 0; j <= gearsB.length - 1; j++){
            if(gearsA[i]>=gearsB[j]){
                distance = Math.abs(((double)gearsB[j] / (double)gearsA[i]) -
                        ratio);
            }
            else{
                distance = Math.abs(((double)gearsA[i] / (double)gearsB[j]) -
                        ratio);
            }
            if(distance <= bestDistance){
                bestDistance = distance;
                posRetRatio[0] = i;
                posRetRatio[1] = j;
            }
            else
                bestDistance = bestDistance;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(distance);
    return posRetRatio;
}
```

I can't really find my mistakes. And help is very appreciated!

Comment: Please provide details about the problem, specifically what behavior you are seeing and how that differs from what you want. As an aside, your code would be a lot simpler (and more efficient) if you defined `gearsA` and `gearsB` to be arrays of `double` instead of `int` and got rid of all the casts.

Comment: At the very end, you should probably print `bestDistance`, rather than `distance`?

Comment: why do you think there are any mistakes? what is not working?

Comment: @TedHopp Unless you commented before edit, there are enough details provided. Output must be 2 numbers, whose division must be as close as possible to ration (0.8 in example)...

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: @CrazySabbath - The missing part is what behavior is actually being observed. (Also, what is given is not the actual desired behavior, which presumably is to display the index pair giving the desired ratio, but just the criterion that the desired behavior should satisfy. It would help to know what indices are being reported and what indices should be reported, all of which is missing.)

Comment: Thank you for the tips! It is  part of the problem that the arrays are int, so it wasn't my choice. But I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: And sorry, I just printed "distance" for testing purposes, to see what was going wrong (0.12307692307692308 is what comes out)

Comment: @ Ted Hopp The expected output: 1 0
What I get: 0 1

Comment: 1 0 as in gearsA[1] and gearsB[0]?

Comment: Why would you expect the output to be `1 0`? The ratio 14/18 (which corresponds to `1 0`) is not closer to 0.8 than 16/20 (which corresponds to `0 1` and hits the target ratio exactly).

Comment: Perhaps because OP is looking for a gear A / gear B ratio, but the code actually calculates the opposite? (B/A)? EDIT: Ah well it always calulates the lower

Comment: @davida. - The code seems to be computing the minimum of A[i]/B[j] and B[j]/A[i].

Comment: ah right, see it now.

Comment: @TedHopp In my assignment the example says 14/18=0,778 and should be the correct answer. (It doesn't make sense to me either)

Comment: Could it be possible that I should not calculate using both A[i]/B[j] and B[j]/A[i], but only A[i]/B[j]?

That seems to work, but it doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: Perhaps it is wrong to be considering the minimum of A[i]/B[j] and B[j]/A[i] and you should be looking only at A[i]/B[j] (in other words, perhaps `gearA` and `gearB` items can't exchange roles in the gear reduction). It would make sense if, for instance, items in the `gearA` set fit on different diameter axes than those in `gearB`.

Comment: @JenniferWagner Why doesn't it make sense? Judging from your assignment, numerator must be from gearsA and denominator from gearsB.

Comment: Yes now it seems to work! I left away the if/else choosing to calculate A[i]/B[j] or B[j]/A[i]

I was so focused on that being possible.

Thanks for everyone's help! If you have any other tips on improving the code, I'm listening!